# Do I need to install a wireless patch for ASUS X205TA after upgrading the kernel?

Tags: wireless, kernel, asus

Looking at the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA) WiFi section it has a link to a WiFi patch and under it says that WiFi works in kernel > 4.0.

Do I still need the WiFi patch if I upgrade to kernel 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No patch needed for 4* kernels. We need these two files in the right place for WiFi to work on this device.

```
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
```

The first one was present & correctly located when I installed 16.04. Previously we used a file from Android and this is still mentioned in old guides, but if you don't have it, you can now get it from the Linux firmware repository:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

This creates a new directory - copy the correct file from it to the right place:

```
sudo cp linux-firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
```

you might want to delete the cloned directory after that, as it is quite big.

The other file is already in the system but in the wrong place. It needs to be copied to the same directory as the .bin file and renamed like this:

```
sudo cp /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/nvram-74b00bd9-805a-4d61-b51f-43268123d113 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.txt
```

Wi-Fi works after reboot :)

Answer (score 1):

I still had problems with the `brcmfmac` driver on Ubuntu 16.04. I had to manually reload the driver module `brcmfmac` after login - otherwise Network Manager would endlessly try to connect - ask for password - attempt to connect again - and so on, and on.

So I added this to `/etc/init.d/rc.local` to automatically restart it after login:

```
# BEGIN restart wifi
modprobe -r brcmfmac
sleep 5s
modprobe  brcmfmac
# END restart wifi
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications by Zanna. Such long time ago - Back then I actually knew how to linux.